# Preventing cannibalisation across content mentioning same keywords through hyperlinks to core content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, keywords

Is it possible to prevent cannibalisation by hyperlinking a keyword on a piece of content to the core content that is optimised for that keyword?

Example of what I mean:

Core content - optimised for keywords 'climate champions' and 'climate soluations.'

If I then use the keyword 'climate champions' in another piece of content, but hyperlink the 'climate champions' text to the core content above, will this help prevent cannibalisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically to the question but which may not help solve a problem:

Currently the page being linked to benefits the greatest by the link in regards to both the text being used within the link, and in regards to juice or importance of that page. (HE WHO GETS THE MOST LINKS WINS)! But the page doing the linking also has a benefit ... the amounts of benefit are subject to how the search engine wants to adjust it algos. (HE WHO HAS THE BEST THEME, (completeness of the subject), WINS)

### Duplicate content and Cannibalization are two different things.

### For Duplication

Remove the duplicate content or change it so that it is not a duplicate. IE Champions is about people or organizations, while Solutions about things people need to do.

### For Cannibalization

If you have pages on your site that are ranking above the pages you want listed first. Then focus on making that page, which is seen as not as good, better. Don't fix the page that is doing well.

Google will not allow one site to flood a search page with ten listings even if their 10 pages are better than all the other pages on the internet. You can generally have two listing; not including social media / YouTube.

Google will list what it considers the best page first. IE cannibalisation of the page you consider the best page.

If your sub pages have more links towards them, lots of good quality content, and therefore are ranking better than you main page. Improve your main page. or add a link from your sub pages toward your main page ... IE treat the sub page like a landing page.

### Navigation as a tool, (and subject theme) for which page is best.

Links on a page are considered in determining how well that page covers a topic. IE if you have three pages, 1> xyz climate champions 2> xyz climate solutions 3> xyz climate resources. and Climate resources has original content and links to climate champions and climate solutions, (say in the sidebar). Both Champions and Solutions link to resources but not each other. Resources wins for most links and most complete coverage.

Searching:
Climate Champions should show Climate Champions,
Climate Solutions should show Climate Solutions, and
Climate Resources should show Climate Resources.

Searching
xyz Climate should show Climate Resources as we have setup the navigation to make that the page which covers the topic the best. Although XYZ Climate is listed on all pages. Under XYZ Climate you may get a 2nd listing of either Champions or Solutions depending on which one of those pages Google thinks is 2nd best ... 3rd best may show on next page of listings.

---

Another framing of what is happening is you are not losing the main page but rather replacing the main page with a sub page which is better within the search.

And as the algo changes over time the new algo may consider a different page to be the best. Not meaning people will not find you, meaning they will enter the site from a different landing page. I don't consider that a problem.

### If you are leveraging with youTube

Link from the description to the page you want listed first.